# Triple integral of portion of cone (cylindrical polar coordinates)?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$V$ is the portion of the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;$ for $\; x\geq 0.$
Find $$\iiint\limits_{V} xe^{-z} dV.$$
I am trying to solve this question.  The answer is supposed to be just $4.$

I have worked out the limits as

$0\leq z \leq \infty\;$ and 
$\;-\pi/2\leq  \theta \leq \pi/2\;$ and $\;0\leq R \leq z.$ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check if I've edited it correctly.

Comment: yes, thankyou. For future, how does one use latex here?

Comment: We are curious to know what the issue was with the evaluation.

Comment: @Pumpkinpeach Refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @gimusi for the calculation for integral of z^3e^-z as in @ lucky's answer below (line 5) I got z^4/4 (e^-z) and if I evaluate that between z limits I got 0?

Comment: You can "open" one from above with R-mouse, then choose Show Math As --> Tech Commands --> click . Important: Each formula has to be embraced by dollars :)

Comment: @Pumpkinpeach Ah ok that's a minor/secondary issue. The most important thing is to have a correct set up and you did this part properly. Well done.Bye

Comment: @Pumpkinpeach the antiderivative is not $\frac{1}{4}z^4e^{-z}$! You have to be careful, since $z^3e^{-z}$ is a product of functions of $z$. You must use integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

With the bounds you have stated, the integral is in fact finite:
\begin{align*}
\iiint_Vxe^{-z}dV&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^\infty\int_0^ze^{-z}r^2\cos\theta\,drdzd\theta\\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^\infty\frac{z^3}{3}e^{-z}\cos\theta\, rdrdzd\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(-e^{-z}(z^3+3z^2+3z+6)\right)\big\rvert_0^\infty\cos\theta\, rdrdzd\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}6\cos\theta\, rdrdzd\theta\\
&=2(\sin\theta)\big\rvert_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
&=4
\end{align*}
The $z$ integration requires integrating by parts a few times, and then taking a limit.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask how you got −e−z(z3+3z2+3z+6) in line 3? Is that just a condensed version of the by parts?

Comment: Yes. I did it by parts by hand... then checked good old Wolfram Alpha to make sure I had not made a silly mistake, which had simplified it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the limit you have indicate, which seems to be correct, we should have

$$\int\int\limits_{V}\int xe^{-z} dV=\int_0^\infty dz \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta \int_0^z R^2\cos \theta e^{-z}dR$$

Maybe you forgot the $R \,dR \,dz \,d\theta$ term or simply you have made a wrong evaluation.

Note that the one presented here works fine: [**Integral evaluation**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20R%5E2%20cos%20t%20e%5E(-z)%20dR%20dt%20dz%20z%3D0..inf%20t%3D-pi%2F2..pi%2F2R%3D0..z).

Comment: $dV=rdrdzd\theta$ is correct. The Jacobian is just $r$.